# Show that a compact metric space is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

We will say a metric space $X$ is **bounded** if, for some $M>0$ and $x\in X$, the entire space $X$ is contained in $B_M(x)=\{y\in X:d(x,y)\leq M\}$. Show that a compact metric space is bounded.

I was attempting to write it up as a totally bounded compact metric space using a finite set so that all the $B_M$'s cover $X$. I am not sure if this is the correct and I am struggling with how to write it up.  I have been researching it for a very long time and this so far seems to be an approach, not sure. Please show details so I can understand.

Comment: Hint: consider a fixed $x\in X$ and balls centered at $x$ with increasing radii.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Pick any $x\in X$. Then $\{B_n(x):n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is an open cover of $X$. $X$ is compact, so ... ?

Comment: I am struggling and am new to this.  Is taking an approach using compactness to get a finite cover of balls radius one and assuming X is unbounded to get a contradiction that the sequence does not contain a convergent subsequence. Thus, showing X is bounded seem to be a correct approach?

Comment: @user217189: You can do it that way, but it's a little easier to use the open cover that I suggested: that way you can avoid having to use the triangle inequality. Show that the collection that I suggested really is an open cover of $X$, take a finite subcover, and show that one member of the subcover actually contains all the others. That largest member must then be $X$ and therefore gives you the bound that you want.

Comment: Is this what is referred to as a totally bounded approach?

Comment: @user217189: I've never encountered such a term. There is a notion of total boundedness, but it's not involved here.

Comment: @user217189: You're welcome. You may be trying to make it too hard. Suppose that $\{B_{n_1}(x),\ldots,B_{n_k}(x)\}$ is a finite subcover. You can assume that $n_1<\ldots<n_k$. Can you see why $B_{n_1}(x)\subseteq\ldots\subseteq B_{n_k}(x)$? And hence why $B_{n_k}(x)=X$?

Comment: That is my problem as it has taken a long time to come up with something real formal and I keep trying different approaches.  Is that actually all there is to it?

Comment: @user217189: That's really all there is to it. In general you should go for the idea first and *then* try to make it more formal.

Comment: @user217189: You're very welcome.

Comment: One last question that may be dumb, the sub index n1,...,nk.  Are you referring to each open ball in general as far as location or specifically referring to increasing radius?

Comment: @user217189: Those numbers would be a subset of $\Bbb Z^+$, and if you list them in increasing order, then the balls are listed in order of increasing radius.

Answer (score 0):

Let  $C=\{B(x,1) :x \in X \}$, which is an open cover of $ X$. For the non-trivial case $X \ne \phi,$ let $\{B(x_j,1) :1 \le j \le n\}$ be a finite sub-cover  .Let $K= \max \{d(x_i,x_j) : 1\leq i \leq j \leq n\}.$ For any  $x,y$ in $X$,  we have $x \in B(x_u,1)$ and $y \in B(x_v,1)$ for some $u,v$.  So $d(x,y) \leq d(x,x_u)+d(x_u,x_v)+d(x_v,y)\ <  1+K+1=K+2.$ So let $x$ be any member of $X$ and let $M=K+2$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it is not bounded. Then there exists a sequence ${x_n}$ s.t. ${x_n} \to \infty$ .
Since $X$ is compact, there exists a convergent subsequence ${(x_n)_k}$ of ${x_n}$ s.t. ${(x_n)_k} \to$ some $x$, $x$ in $X$. But ${(x_n)_k} \to \infty$ as well. By uniqueness of limit, this is a contradiction. Thus $X$ is bounded.